# Controlling element sizes depending on screen size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there any way in flutter in which we can size everything in our app depending on screen size like `rem` property in css. Because all widgets demand sizes in pixel sizes which can be different for different screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because all widgets demand sizes in pixel sizes

Actually, flutter uses [density independent pixels (dp)](https://material.io/design/layout/pixel-density.html#density-independence) for width/height arguments. dp actually scale with resolution, meaning 1 dp is displayed as the same PHYSICAL distance on every device.

But for relative layout there are some options:

1. [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)
2. [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)
3. [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)
4. [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)
5. [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)
6. [other layout options](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout)